# How to print arabic text in ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arabic, arabic-support

How can I print an arabic string as it is in a ruby on rails application.
This's my sample arabic text :

```
رمز التحقق لتسجيل الدخول إلى تطبيق الاختبار الخاص بي هو: 3155. لا تشارك الرمز مع أي شخص لأنه سري
```

> رمز التحقق لتسجيل الدخول إلى تطبيق الاختبار الخاص بي هو: 3155. لا تشارك الرمز مع أي شخص لأنه سري

The number 3155 is a variable I want to put in the text above. But I'm unable to do this, as it's somehow getting changed, when I change the constant number to handle variable like #{otp}

> رمز التحقق لتسجيل الدخول إلى تطبيق الاختبار الخاص بي هو: #{otp}. لا تشارك الرمز مع أي شخص لأنه سري

```
رمز التحقق لتسجيل الدخول إلى تطبيق الاختبار الخاص بي هو: #{otp}. لا تشارك الرمز مع أي شخص لأنه سري
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We need some sample code to run showing what you've tried, along with any errors received.

Comment: @theTinMan Already added sample code of what I tried. Was trying to integrate the otp variable into my string, but it's not printing the otp variable value, instead it's printing as it is, and the meaning of the text when i tried google translate is also changing.
shared the sample text in 2nd quote

Comment: Did you use single or double quotes with your string? Who do you actually output the string? In ERB, in the console?

Comment: used double quotes. and output the string in console.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend  using **Internationalization (I18n) API** docs [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#organization-of-locale-files)

then in local `config/locales/ar.yml` you can define a key for this sentence 
`note: رمز التحقق لتسجيل الدخول إلى تطبيق الاختبار الخاص بي هو: %{otp}. لا تشارك الرمز مع أي شخص لأنه سري`

and in your application

```
I18n.t 'note' ,  otp: otp
```

trying to write Arabic inside your code will make you have really hard times